# how to include node.js modules with following pattern

Tags: node.js, module

### a.js

```
    if(typeof(MAIN) == "undefined") var MAIN = {};
    (function(_e) {

    function SLfunction(yea,mx,dx){
    var out = "abc";
    return(out)
    }
     _e.SLfunction = function(yea,mx,dx) {
        return SLfunction(yea,mx,dx);
      };
    }(MAIN));
```

---

### b.js

```
if(typeof(MAIN) == "undefined") var MAIN = {};
(function(_e) {

 function SLfunction2(yea,mx,dx){
 var out = "def";
 return(out)
 }

 _e.SLfunction2 = function(yea,mx,dx) {
    return SLfunction2(yea,mx,dx);
  };
}(MAIN));
```

---

main.js

```
var MAIN =(a.js)
var MAIN =(b.js)
```

How to include the modules into main.js so both SLfunction and SLfunction2 able to use. Thanks

Comment: Fix three problems to use. 1) You need to export the functions in  a.js and b.js. 2) Use require in main.js. 3) Fix the variable name in main.js. You are using the same variable name for both a.js and b.js. The syntax is incorrect as well.

Comment: Node [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) follow commonjs spec.

Comment: Thanks, If I use in html I'm able to use the function by MAIN.SLfunction() and MAIN.SLfunction2(); if the a.js and b.js consisted 20 functions So do I need to exports all the function Name ?

Comment: Yes, correct. each js file needs an export.

Comment: Could you please describe  the function for "MAIN" and  "_e" in this example.